# Aggregate/group points by value, and label aggregated point with aggregate expression (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, labeling, geometry-generator, grouping, aggregate

## Problem Statement

I have a layer of multiple points, and I am trying to:

- Aggregate/group the points by their attribute values, so that one point is drawn for each group of points with matching attributes
- Label the aggregated points, with an aggregate label expression that combines attribute values from the individual points

## Example

Here is a layer of several points, of a few cities in California. These points are colored by the greater metropolitan area they are part of (Sacramento, San Francisco, Los Angeles).

[image: simple example dataset of what I'm working with]

I would like to dynamically group these points by their metro area, and label these grouped points with each city's name and population, which would look like this:

[image: desired result]

Here is the example data/project: https://github.com/Marcus-Richmond/example-datasets/blob/main/Aggregate%20Points.zip

## Obstacles

1. The key here is that I would like to achieve this result dynamically. I would like to avoid creating new layers (although if I had to say, create a virtual layer that grouped the metro areas dynamically, that might be ok).
2. I've tried the following expression with the geometry generator for the symbol and the labels, but cannot get it to work.

`collect($geometry, group_by:="Metro Area")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Point symbols:**

In your categorized renderer change the symbol to geometry generator and use
`centroid(collect($geometry,"Metro Area"))` as expression:

[image]

**Labels:**

Use `array_to_string(array_agg("Name" || ' ('  || format_number("Population") || ')',group_by:="Metro Area",order_by:="Population"),'\n')` as label value. And `centroid(collect($geometry,"Metro Area"))` as geometry generator point symbol:

[image]

Go to rendering and check "Show label" box as data defined override and use `array_find(array_agg($id,"Metro Area",order_by:=$id),$id)=0` as expression to avoid duplicated labels:

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @MrXsquared. I'm hoping to do more complex aggregation of points/labels and this is a huge help in getting me started. I appreciate the help.